# innerHtml in Angular 15 does'nt display correctly the <tr><td> data in each column of a html table

Tags: angular, html-table, innerhtml, angular15, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I'm trying to fill a html table with data (that I get from a http request) that are parsed in string. Like the string with data contains the **`<tr>/<td>` markups**, I'm trying to render them with the **innerHtml** of Angular. But **all the data are displayed in the first column.**

My request parse for fill the dataContent (the data for filled the html table):

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xml = parser.parseFromString(res.toString(), "text/xml");
this.dataContent = xml.querySelector("TABLEDATA")?.innerHTML;
```

How the dataContent looks like (with the right tr td markups, perfect for the [innerHtml] of Angular):

```
<TR><TD>[some data]</TD><TD>[some data]</TD>... </TR><TR>...</TR>...etc.
```

So I write it in the tbody of my html table with the **innerHtml in purpose to filling each column with the dataContent:**

```
<table id="first-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>_id</th>
            <th>_time</th>
            <th>_ra</th>
            <th>_dec</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody [innerHtml]="dataContent"></tbody>
</table>
```

All the `<tr><td>` markups in the dataContent are processed (it's not showed up in the web page) **BUT all the data are displayed only in the first column**. The inspector view is like:

```
<tbody _ngcontent-fsr-c1="">
[all the data]
</tbody>
```

I develop the same web app in react and the unique difference in the code is instead of

```
<tbody [innerHtml]="dataContent"></tbody> // in Angular
```

```
<tbody dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: ref.current }}></tbody> // in React
```

And in React, it's work perfectly fine and, **ref.current** is exactly **the same as dataContent.**

What can be the problem then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your solution and it gives me a `"WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see https://g.co/ng/security#xss"`. But despite this, it seems to display all my data (but it's not easy to be sure because I have a lot of data).

So to handle this warning, I follow https://careydevelopment.us/blog/angular-how-to-deal-with-the-sanitizing-html-stripped-some-content-issue. We will **write a pipe** and we override Angular's default behavior. You need to **be sure** that will **not be dangerous in your case**.

Create a nosanitizerpipe.ts file in a util folder. With this code in it:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'noSanitize' })
export class NoSanitizePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(html: string): SafeHtml {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

Import  it in the module.ts:

```
import { NoSanitizePipe } from '~/util/nosanitizepipe';
```

And declare it:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
...
    NoSanitizePipe
  ]
...
```

And use it like this in the template:

```
<tbody [innerHtml]="dataContent | noSanitize"></tbody>
```

Where dataContent isn't processed with `sanitizeTableBody(bodyHtml: string)` method.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old problem, and the only way I found for solving it - even though it's not too clean and readable - is to sanitize it:

introduce new var:
`sanitizedData: any = null;`

in onInit do: `this.sanitizeData = this.sanitizeTableBody(this.data);` where `data` is your string containing table data.

Create a method:

```
sanitizeTableBody(bodyHtml: string): SafeHtml | null {
   const tableContent = `<table>${bodyHtml}</table>`;
   const contentSanitized = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, tableContent);
   const strippedContent = contentSanitized.replace(/^<table>(.*)<\/table>$/, '$1');
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(strippedContent);
}
```

Then call it from template:

`<tbody [innerHtml]="sanitizedData"></tbody>`

Stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ttmxkf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).